# How to pass index of sqlite database to another page in flutter app using sqflite?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, android-database, sqflite

I am making an app in which users can save the transaction data which they can do by filling out the following form
[image: form]

The transactions then will be saved in the database and can be shown to users on the following screen [image: show]

Now what I want is that if I click on one of these transactions I should be redirected to another page, for this, I need to pass the index of transactions in onTap() so that it can be passed on another screen, am I right about it? If yes please help me with it I am new to flutter and I don't know how to do it.

The code I am using to create my database is:

```
await database.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_EXPENSES ("
      "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
      "$COLUMN_NAME TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_AMOUNT INTEGER,"
      "$COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES INTEGER,"
      "$COLUMN_CATEGORY TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_DATETIME TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_COMMENTS TEXT"
      ")",
    );
```

The code which I am using for mapping:

```
class expense {
  int id;
  String name;
  int amount;
  bool isUnnecessaryExpenses;
  String category;
  DateTime dateTime;
  String pickedDate;
  String comments;

expense({this.id, this.name, this.amount, this.isUnnecessaryExpenses,  this.category, this.dateTime, this.pickedDate, this.comments});

Map toMap() {
  var map = {
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_NAME: name,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_AMOUNT: amount,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES: isUnnecessaryExpenses ? 1  : 0,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_CATEGORY: category,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_DATETIME: pickedDate,
    DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_COMMENTS: comments,
  };

  if (id != null) {
    map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_ID] = id;
  }

  return map;
  }

 expense.fromMap(Map map) {
  id = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_ID];
  name = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_NAME];
  amount = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_AMOUNT];
  isUnnecessaryExpenses = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES]  == 1;
  category= map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_CATEGORY];
  pickedDate = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_DATETIME];
  comments = map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_COMMENTS];
  }
 }
```

I am using following code for displaying transaction:

```
   class ExpenseList extends StatefulWidget {
   const ExpenseList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
  _ExpenseListState createState() => _ExpenseListState();
  }

 class _ExpenseListState extends State<ExpenseList> {
  @override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 DatabaseProvider.db.getExpenses().then(
  (ExpenseList) {
    BlocProvider.of<ExpenseBloc>(context).add(SetExpenses(ExpenseList));
    },
   );
  }
 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: BlocConsumer<ExpenseBloc, List<expense>>(
      builder: (context, expenseList) {
        return ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            expense expensess = expenseList[index];
            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  border: Border.all(width: 2,color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(
                    expensess.name
                        .substring(0, 1)
                        .toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  expensess.name ?? "Title",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "Amount: ${expensess.amount.toString()}"
                      "\nDate: ${expensess.pickedDate}\n"
                  ,style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  var currID= expensess.id; ///// line 1 /////////
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ViewTransaction()));
                      }
                  ));
                },
             
          itemCount: expenseList.length,
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(color: Colors.black),
        );
      },
      listener: (BuildContext context, ExpenseList) {},
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => ExpenseForm()),
       ),
      ),
    );
   }  
  }
```

I am trying to do it as shown in **///// line 1 /////////** but I am not sure about it and also I am having no idea that how can I do it in the viewTransaction page.

Please help me.
Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to pass id to ViewTransaction Widget as parameter

```dart
int expenseId = expensess.id;
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ViewTransaction(expenseId:expenseId)));
```

Your ViewTransaction Widget should be something like this.

```dart
class ViewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final int expenseId;

  ViewTransaction({this.expenseId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, can you please help me with how to fetch data using this index as well??

Comment: I mean how can I get the Name, amount, etc fields in ViewTransaction page. Please help with it.

Comment: Well there are two ways 1st you can pass whole expense object as parameter in ViewTransaction instead of id. 2nd You need to make sqlite call to fetch that particular record from db based on id you get.